# О смысле выражения "делать ноги"

Tags: фразеология

Вот интересно, почему, убегая, ноги — делают? Есть какие-нибудь соображения?

Answer (score 1):

А  почему  "кинуть  кости"  это  переместиться  в  каком-то  направлении ? Так  же  и  с  ногами.  Сленг.   Но,  предположительно,  из  одесской  "мовы".  Типовая  конструкция  в  речи  одесситов :  делать +  разные другие  слова.  Стоит  в  ряду  таких  выражений  как :  делать  ночь ( спать ),  делать  погоду ( устанавливать  свои  порядки ),  делать  морду  ( делать  вид ),  делать  ноги  (  убегать, сбегать ) и  т.д.  См.  Валерий  Смирнов. "Полутолковый  словарь  одесского  языка."    http://www.uchiyaziki.ru/index.php/slovar-argo-slenga-gargonniy   Надеюсь,  что  это  уже  ответ.   P.S.  Ни  в  одном  из  представленных  на  этом  сайте  фразеологических  словарей  этого  выражения  нет.  Даль  тоже  не  приводит.  Присутствует  только  в  словаре  воровского  арго ( онлайн  на  Яндексе ), но  этимологии  там  нет.  Только  значение - убегать.

Comment: Ну, слег - это не ответ. Сленговые выражения тоже откуда-то берутся.))

Comment: Совершенно  с  вами  согласен. Ищу  вот.  Да  что-то  не  находится.

Comment: Получается,  что  это  не  сленг,  а  диалектизм.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю ответа, но для себя решила, что речь о попрошайках, прикидывающихся безногими. В момент опасности им приходилось снова "делать" ноги и убегать. "Делай ноги" - убегай.

Comment: Остроумно  и  убедительно.  Но  и  в  словарь  фразеологизмов  заглянуть  не  худо.